# How to get the date when a dimension changes?

Tags: tableau-api

in my dataset one customer can change his subscription several times.

How can I get the date as a new field when a customer's subscription is changed?

Here is sample data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Here is the workbook: https://community.tableau.com/s/contentdocument/0694T000004aZ8NQAU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a data like this

```
Cust    date    subscription
ABC 01-01-2021  adv
ABC 02-01-2021  adv
ABC 03-01-2021  pre
ABC 04-01-2021  pre
ABC 05-01-2021  pre
ABC 06-01-2021  basic
ABC 07-01-2021  basic
BCD 08-01-2021  basic
BCD 09-01-2021  basic
BCD 10-01-2021  adv
BCD 11-01-2021  adv
BCD 12-01-2021  pre
```

I made a calculated field

```
LOOKUP(min([Cust]+[subscription]), -1) = min([Cust]+[subscription])
```

Made some changes in table calculation

[image]

and added this field to filters shelf.  It now filters out the desired unwanted records

see it in action

[image]

Comment: Glad that it helped.  Please also consider upvote as usually desired on SO.